# How to use one-way ANOVA to analyse treatment effects?

Tags: r, anova

I'm doing a lab report at the moment, and am analysing 5 years of data to provide a conclusion on bacterial sensitivity to specific antibiotics. My data consists of several replicates measuring the size of the clearance zone for bacterial growth (where they won't grow) for each antibiotic tested. I've done Shapiro-Wilkes to test normality, and have moved on to trying one-way ANOVA but since I don't have 2 distinct variables to test I'm having trouble doing the data analysis efficiently (if I sit and try every combination of 8 antibiotics over a 5 year period when the experiment is repeated every year I might have a nervous breakdown). Is there a way to reorganise the data to do this properly? How do I use one-way ANOVA to do this efficiently? I'm fairly new to R, so have been having trouble working this out myself with limited knowledge and understanding of the language.

From what I can tell, one-way ANOVA is supposed to read with the following syntax in R:

```
model->aov(variable1 ~ variable2, data=dataframe)
```

My issue is in not really having two variables to measure, so I'm unsure of how to reorganise it to complete the test efficiently? I essentially have antibiotic1-8, repeated multiple times and with different data over 5 years.

Comment: You do have more than one variable to measure - or at least to record:  bacterial strain, year and size oc clearance zone.  size of clearance zone is your dependent, year and strain are your independent or predictor variables.  If you need more help, this question is better suited to stats.stackexchange, and I am recommending that the question is migrated over there.

Comment: Your assignmewnt arrow is wrong, change `->`  to  `<-`

Answer (score 0):

You have at least three variables:  Clearance, antibiotic, and year. If you are ignoring year, then your model is

```
m1 <- aov(clearance~antibiotic, data = dataframe)
```

I am a little worried about the word "replicate" but I'm guessing that just means the same antibiotic, in which case you are OK. (I hope that you are just using one strain of bacteria).